# Python folium fetching csv data to the jinja macro template

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet, folium

I have the jinja macro template provided to my code, which executes the Leaflet circle creation.

I would like to include the .csv data in this template when possible

```
df = pd.read_csv("survey.csv")

class Circle(folium.ClickForMarker):
_template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var circle_job = L.circle();
            function newMarker(e){
                circle_job.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                circle_job.setRadius({{rad}});
                circle_job.getPopup({{role}})
                      if {{role}} = "Contractor" {
                      color="red"
                      }else{
                      color="black"
                      }
                circle_job.bringToFront()
                parent.document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat;
                parent.document.getElementById("longitude").value =lng;
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newMarker);      
         {% endmacro %}
          """)  # noqa

  def __init__(self, popup=None):
    super(Circle, self).__init__(popup)
    self._name = 'Circle'

job_range = Circle()

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
    lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
    sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
    phone = df.at[i, 'phone']
    role = df.at[i, 'role']
    rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])
```

is it possible something like this?

A similar approach was here:

[How add circle markers to a rendered folium map embedded in a QWebEngineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614721/how-add-circle-markers-to-a-rendered-folium-map-embedded-in-a-qwebengineview)

**UPDATE I:**

I tried recently something like this:

```
class Circle(MacroElement):
 _template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var {{this.get_name()}} = L.circle();
            function newCircle(e){ 
{{this.get_name()}}.setLatLng(e.latlng)
.addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                {{this.get_name()}}.setRadius({{rad}});
                {{this.get_name()}}.setStyle({
                color: 'black',
                fillcolor: 'black'
                });
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newCircle);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa

def __init__(self,
             popup=None
             ):
    super(Circle, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'Circle'

for i,row in df.iterrows():
  lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
  lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
  sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
  phone = df.at[i, 'phone']
  role = df.at[i, 'role']
  rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])


popup = '<b>Phone: </b>' + str(df.at[i,'phone'])
work_range = os.path.join('survey_range.geojson')
job_range = Circle()
```

Now I lost some features, whereas the Js console says nothing. Is it possible to fetch data from df.iterrows directly to the Macroelement?

**UPDATE II**

I tried to fiddle with def__init__ section and now my code looks as follows:

class Circle(MacroElement):

```
  def __init__(self,
             popup=None,
             draggable=False,
             edit_options=None,
             radius=rad
             #lat,
             #lng
             ):
    super(Circle, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'Circle',
    self.radius = radius,
    
    self._template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var circle_job = L.circle();
            function newCircle(e){
                
 circle_job.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                circle_job.setRadius(50000);
                circle_job.setStyle({
                color: 'black',
                fillcolor: 'black'
                });
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newCircle);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa
    
for i,row in df.iterrows():
lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
phone = df.at[i, 'phone']
role = df.at[i, 'role']
rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])
```

and the error thrown is:   **The rad is not defined**

Is there any way of including the stuff from inside of `df.iterrows()` in the `jinja2` template via defining the `def___init?`